# Find all occurences of a value in a list

Tags: c#, find-occurrences

I am trying to get the number of how many times player.userID shows in a list but I can't seem to figure out how, I have searched the internet for an hour now.

```
        class ConfigData
        {

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Ban")]
            public uint ban = 3;
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Kick")]
            public uint kick = 2;
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Banned Message")]
            public string kickMessage = "You are banned";

        }

        class StoredData
        {
            public List<ulong> Reports = new List<ulong>();
            public List<ulong> Banned = new List<ulong>();
            public List<ulong> Kicked = new List<ulong>();

        }
        void OnPlayerConnected(BasePlayer player)
        {
            int count = storedData.Reports.Count(reportedID => reportedID == player.userID);
            Puts($"{player.userID} has {count} reports");
            if (count >= configData.ban)
            {
                storedData.Banned.Add(player.userID);
                SaveData();
                return;
            }
            if (storedData.Banned.Contains(player.userID))
            {
                Network.Net.sv.Kick(player.net.connection, rust.QuoteSafe(configData.kickMessage));
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
```

I can post the full code if needed.

Comment: Don't you mean `>= configData.ban` ?

Comment: What is `storedData.Reports` a list of? Do the items have a `UserId` property?

Comment: no if its == to that then it would ban the player but the count says this.
https://i.imgur.com/UrvJLCQ.png

Comment: @TheReality Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: the data is a ulong list

Answer (score 2):

The `Count` method accepts a lambda that tells it the condition on which to count.

Since your reports are just a list of user IDs, all you need to do is:

```
int count = storedData.Reports.Count(reportedID => reportedID == player.userID); 
if (count >= configData.ban)   // NOTE: changed this to >=
{
  ...
}
```

As a side note, if it was a list of objects instead, and you wanted to compare to a property named `someProperty`, then it would be:
`report => report.someProperty == player.userID`.

A lambda is just a shorthand for a function; the part before the `=>` is the parameter list (here, it just accepts  a single parameter - the current element of `storedData.Reports`). The parameter name is arbitrary (your choice).

The part behind the `=>` is the function body, with implicit return, so
`reportedID == player.userID` is like
`{ return reportedID == player.userID; }`.

The `Count` method basically walks through the IDs in `Reports`, and for each one, it asks the lambda if it should count it or not, by passing that ID to the lambda, and checking if the lambda returns `true` or `false`.

P.S.
In your code it says:

```
if (!storedData.Banned.Contains(player.userID)) { /* kick */ }
```

Are you sure you want to kick the players that are *not* in the banned list? Check the logic that relates to kicking/banning (maybe do some tests), it doesn't look quite right to me.

Comment: OP said something like Reports is `List<ulong>` so i don't think we have enough info to solve this question yet.

Comment: @Charles No, I think the `ulong` is the user ID, and the error message is that Count expects a lambda but was given an `ulong`. Besides, I've given enough info for the OP to be able to solve the problem themselves, even if I didn't get it quite right.

Comment: I don't think that's the only problem, it would probably be better to store Reports inside a `Dictionary`

Comment: How do i post fullcode?

Comment: I updated it, now look it should look understandable

Comment: @TheReality OK, I've also updated the answer to better reflect your code, but have you tried what I suggested?

Comment: It doenst ban everyone it checks the list and if user is on list it bans, I'm adding them to ban list if they are on report list more than 3 times.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean the ! was there and made it opposite, thanks I fixed that now after testing it.

Comment: For some reason its adding 2 reports and 3 bans to the data file. here is the function and it seems to happen when i save the data.